# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal and textboxes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i tried to put  a textbox on the angular ui bootstrap modal component.

For demonstration I changed the example which works with a list of items to a textbox.

http://plnkr.co/edit/itpxmvXL0JDZ5B1q9IEI

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
              <input type="text" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>


        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <div >Username: {{ username }}</div>
</div>
```

And here the javascript:

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.username ='';

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        username: function () {
          return $scope.username;
        }

      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (username) {
      $scope.username = username;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

  $scope.username = 'A';

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.username);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel','');
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. For now you need to use the famous dot in your ngModel expression:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3ZQ3G0ngMpW2vVbJVN0Y?p=preview

We are going to do it a bit easier on people in 0.12.0, see https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2110